# How to fix tensorflow (GPU) import error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

first time here.

So I was trying to accelerate tensorflow with CUDA.
After I installed required Nvidia drivers, CUDA toolset, Cudnn;
Created virtual environment and installed tf-gpu there.
Versions of cuda set - as requred at TF gpu setup page, VS Community 2019

Then right after attempt to import tf in that env, I encountered error, here's traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59 

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in 
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    241         else:
--> 242             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    243     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    341             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 342         return _load(spec)
    343 

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in 
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in 
     48 import numpy as np
     49 
---> 50 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     51 
     52 # Protocol buffers

~\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in 
     67 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     68 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 69   raise ImportError(msg)
     70 
     71 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\krive\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\krive\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\krive\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\krive\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\krive\.conda\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please help out, what I missed?

Comment: It is probably some incopatibility among Tensorflow, CUDA and CuDNN versions. Check [this answer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41453#issuecomment-659418940) in a similar GitHub issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: can you post the version of TensorFlow, CuDNN and CUDA being used? also if you are on windows, what version of Visual Studio you have